# PHP pass multiple attributes

Tags: php, html

I want to send both the "Grade"-value and the value $chosenBarName in rateFunction.php when i press the "submit"-button, is there a easy way to do this? I only succed with getting the "Grade"-value...

```
$chosenID = $row['BarName'];
echo "<td>" . $row['BarID'] . " " . $row['BarName'] . "<br>" . $row['Website'] . "</td>";
    <form method="post" action="rateFunction.php">
        <select name="grade">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a hidden field with the value of the BarName in it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="BarName" value="<? echo $row['BarName']?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

put the barName as a hidden input inside the form tags

```
$chosenID = $row['BarName'];
echo "<td>" . $row['BarID'] . " " . $row['BarName'] . "<br>" . $row['Website'] . "</td>";
    <form method="post" action="rateFunction.php">

        <input type="hidden" name="barname" value="<?= $row['BarName'];?>">

        <select name="grade">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your hidden tag!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your  tag you can render some hidden element to keep the info you need.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="barname" value="'.$choosebarname.'" />';
```

should do the trik

Answer (score 0):

Include a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $row['BarName'];?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field: `<input type=hidden name='chosenBarName' value='<?php echo $chosenBarName ?>'/>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as a field, you can use a `hidden` field for that

```
$chosenID = $row['BarName'];
echo "<td>" . $row['BarID'] . " " . $row['BarName'] . "<br>" . $row['Website'] . "</td>";
    <form method="post" action="rateFunction.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="chosenBarName" value="<?php echo $row['BarName'];?>"> 
        <select name="grade">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```